# How to check if a list is contained within any of the keys of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hellos guys, I'm trying to check if a all elements of a list are contained in any of the keys of a dictionary as long as they are on the same key, for example;

```
dict = {1:{1,2,3,4,5,6},2:{10,2,9,8,5,7},3:{11,9,3,13},4:{12,8,4,13,14},}
```

I have those 3 list

```
[1,2,9],[2,9,8],[9,8,12]
```

Only the second list should return true as it's values are contained within key 2 of the dictionary the others should all return false

Can someone help find out a way to do it?

Comment: you are checking the *values* of the dictionary, not the *keys*

Comment: Would you be able to do it if you only had to compare the lists to one of the values, like `[1,2,9],[2,9,8],[9,8,12]` to `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`? What if you only had one list, like `[1,2,9]` vs `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`? Did you try using loops to break the problem down into those smaller problems and repeatedly solve them? What *did* you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension with `any` and set operations.

```
d = {1:{1,2,3,4,5,6},2:{10,2,9,8,5,7},3:{11,9,3,13},4:{12,8,4,13,14},}

to_check = [1,2,9],[2,9,8],[9,8,12]

res = [any(j.issuperset(i) for j in d.values()) for i in to_check]
```

Output

```
[False, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm for my problem, that's exactly what i was looking for. Sorry if the question was dumb, I'm just now learning how to code in python.